# ggplot with a subset of levels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot something very simple and I use this code:

```
df_tra %>%
  filter(Theta_param ==1 & Gamma_param==0.76,Int_dis=='Bench' ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Debt, y = Gini_tra , colour =Rho_param )) +
  geom_line()
```

The `Rho_param` has four main levels:

```
.$ Rho_param  : Factor w/ 4 levels "0","0.23","1", "1.2"
```

My question is how I should modify the `colour` option in the ggplot if I want to only take into account a subset of these levels. Say want to plot only for when `Rho_param` is equal to `0` and `1`

Comment: Maybe `colour = ifelse(Rho_param %in% c(0, 1), Rho_param, NA)`. I believe `NA` suppress plotting.

Comment: Sadly, does not produce the expected result. The graph looks weird. (plots look fine when include all levels)

Comment: The try `filter(Rho_param %in% c(0, 1)) %>% ggplot(etc)`.

Comment: it worked, yes. But I was wondering whether there a was a more "direct" way, by changing the option to ggplot instead of subseting the dataset.

Comment: I don't believe so. What you can do is to write a small subsetting function and pass the values you want to filter. Then call `ggplot(data = fun(0, 1), aes(.))` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter your data;
when you want to input your data to ggplot function you can do the following:

```
Data[Data$Rho_param==0 & Data$Rho_param==1,]
```

By doing so, you will not plot any Rho_params other than 0s and 1s.
So the full function can be :

```
ggplot(Data[Data$Rho_param=="0" & Data$Rho_param=="1",], aes(x = Debt, y = Gini_tra , colour =Rho_param )) + geom_line()
```

Comment: Didn't work: got these warnings `Warning messages:
1: Factor `Theta_param` contains implicit NA, consider using `forcats::fct_explicit_na` 
2: Factor `Rho_param` contains implicit NA, consider using `forcats::fct_explicit_na` 
3: Factor `Gamma_param` contains implicit NA, consider using `forcats::fct_explicit_na` 
4: Factor `Int_dis` contains implicit NA, consider using `forcats::fct_explicit_na` `

Comment: DId you try something like this?
ggplot(Data[Data$Rho_param=="0" & Data$Rho_param=="1",], aes(x = Debt, y = Gini_tra , colour =Rho_param )) +
  geom_line()

Comment: I think those `&`s should be `|`s. It's impossible for a value to be both 0 and 1.